# How can I make PIG game for single player?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have already created a game I wanted to make a change in below code.

Every time it rolls it shows **TURN number**,

But I want to show it **once** on **each turn.**

How can i fix it?

```
    using System;
    
    
    namespace PigGamePractice
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            public static int turn=1;
            public static int turnScore;
            public static int totalScore = 0;
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
    
            {
                Dice();
            }
            static void Dice()
            {
                while (turn<=4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("**This is Turn " + turn);
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Role or Hold ?  (r/h) : ");
                    char userChoice = Console.ReadLine()[0];
    
                    if (userChoice == 'r')
                    {
                        Random random = new Random();
                        int diceRoll = random.Next(1, 7);
                        turnScore += diceRoll;
                        totalScore += diceRoll;
                        Console.WriteLine("Dice: "+diceRoll);
                        if (totalScore >= 20)
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine("**You won..!**");
                            Console.WriteLine("Your Total Score is: " + totalScore);
                            break;
                        }
                        if (diceRoll == 1)
                        {
                            totalScore -= turnScore;
                            Console.WriteLine("Turn over..!");
                            Console.WriteLine("Turn Score: 0");
                            Console.WriteLine("Total score: " + totalScore);
                            turnScore = 0;
                            turn++;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    if (userChoice == 'h')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Turn Score: "+turnScore);
                        Console.WriteLine("Total Score: " + totalScore);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        turnScore = 0;
                        turn++;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Every time it rolls it shows TURN number,
But I want to show on each turn **once**.
how can I fix it?

[image]

now I am getting output like this

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. According to your output, your program already outputs the turn number before every action, whether it's a roll or a hold. What exactly do you "want to show on each turn"?

Comment: The turn changes if user press 'h' or user gets 1 
Now to code is doing that only but it is showing on each roll 
instead of that i want to show it on each Turn (When he gets 1 or he press 'h')

Comment: your question is still unclear, If you want to change the turn each time he write "r" you need to take turn++; outside the if  so every loop the turn will change

Comment: One possibility:  Use a variable that keeps track of the last turn you displayed, and only display the turn if the new turn is different from the last turn.  `if (turn != lastTurn) { Console.WriteLine(...);  lastTurn = turn; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try Wyck's method, adds a variable, and compares its value to `turn`.

Second you can add a bool to judge as I did.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static int turn = 1;
        public static int turnScore;
        public static int totalScore = 0;
        //ADD
        public static bool flag = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dice();
        }
        static void Dice()
        {
            while (turn <= 4)
            {
                //ADD
                if (flag)
                    Console.WriteLine("**This is Turn " + turn);

                Console.WriteLine("Role or Hold ?  (r/h) : ");
                char userChoice = Console.ReadLine()[0];

                if (userChoice == 'r')
                {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int diceRoll = random.Next(1, 7);
                    turnScore += diceRoll;
                    totalScore += diceRoll;
                    //ADD
                    flag = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Dice: " + diceRoll);
                    if (totalScore >= 20)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("**You won..!**");
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Total Score is: " + totalScore);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (diceRoll == 1)
                    {
                        totalScore -= turnScore;
                        Console.WriteLine("Turn over..!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Turn Score: 0");
                        Console.WriteLine("Total score: " + totalScore);
                        turnScore = 0;
                        turn++;
                        //ADD
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (userChoice == 'h')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Turn Score: " + turnScore);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total Score: " + totalScore);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    turnScore = 0;
                    turn++;
                    //ADD
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]